# Can I launch an image inside lxc as a GUI?

Tags: containers, virtual-machines

I'm completely new to lxc. I've installed lxc and lxd and created a Linux mint container. I'm getting into and out of mint via the CLI, but as I'm messing around with it I'm wondering: can you, say, launch this and see its desktop environment (provided it has one installed), as in the case of a full-blown VM, or can you only deal with containers in headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

lxc will not provide anything similar to vm GUI but you can try running GNOME shell as per this article
https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/running-gnome-container

when dealing with container I do  not prefer any kind of GUI as it create multiple process to support GUI itself  and container best practice always prefer single task or process in a container.